# Using Node, I can't get a static HTML page to load from the app file

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm trying to load an HTML page to load when a request is made to the app. The HTML loads fine if I put it in a res.end('') function in the server definition but that is dirty. In the below code, I want to load index.html as the root route. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and I've tried using redirect instead of sendFile which also does not work.

```
const pg = require('pg');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const  $ = require('jquery');
const path =  require('path')

const connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://localhost:5432/hiking';

const server = http.createServer((req,res) => {});

var app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});



app.post('/inputs', function(req,res){
    var firstName = req.body.firstName;
    var lastName = req.body.lastName;
    var mountainName = req.body.mountainName;
    console.log(req.body);
});




const client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect();
const query = client.query('SELECT * from public.hike LIMIT 1', (err, res) => {
    if (err){
        console.log(err.stack)
    } else
        console.log(res.rows)
}) ;

console.log("Ready.");

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: `var server = http.createServer(app);` You need to pass in your app to the server. Anyway, you can likely just skip http.createServer and do `app.listen(3000);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a repository that contains the code you're interested in: https://github.com/blakedietz/so-express-static-index

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use('/', express.static('public'))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Comment: Just add that line? I'm guessing no, since doing that didn't work.

Comment: Did you look at the repo code? You’ll also need s static directory named public with an index file at the root of it.